# Tomcat having issues with JAVA files from a WAR File

Tags: tomcat6

Would anyone be able to help me out.  I have code which runs successfully in Eclipse.  But when i create a WAR file and try to run it the Tomcat server is not able to find the JAVA files.  Is there a big different running the code through Eclipse on Tomcat and running the WAR file directly on the Tomcat server.

Any help or advise to help me work out what is going on would be great appreciate, even if it is only a starting point for me to start investigating it myself.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: can you post the error message you are seeing and a listing of the contents of your war file

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat can't do anything with .java files. You need to package the compiled .class files, not the source .java files.